# Getting php results to show after AJAX call without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have three sections on a page. Pending, Accepted, and Denied users. I output all of this data through a php while loop. Next to the Pending users section, for each user in that section I have two buttons (Accept and Deny). When either of those buttons are pressed I run an Ajax call to my php file that updates the users status to either Accepted or Denied (whichever was pressed).

The issue I am having is without letting the page refresh the user's data will not moved to the updated status section(Everything updates correctly on the db side). However, if I move out the `return false;` code the page refreshes, but my `$('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
                $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);` goes away right when the page refreshes, so almost instantly.

I need a way that the page does not refresh, but my user's data is moved to the appropriate section, so my success message still appears.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.approve').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'userRequest_approve.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: $(this).val(), //id
            status: 'Approved' //status
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //do something with the data that got returned
            $("#success").fadeIn();
            $("#success").show();
            $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
            $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
        },
        //type: 'POST'
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Form

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="status">


  <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $pending_id; ?>' id='pending_id' />
    <?php if ($pending_firstname==t rue) { echo "Name - ". $pending_firstname . " " . $pending_lastname . "</br>" . "Username - ". $pending_username . "</br></br>" //echo print_r($_POST); ?>
</form>
<button class="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" value="<?=$pending_id;?>">Approve</button>
<button id="deny" type="submit" form="status" name="deny" value="Denied">Deny</button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<?php ;} else { echo "There are no Pending Requests at this time."; }
```

Code for the html part:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($run);

    if( $numrows ) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            if($row['status'] == "Pending"){

                $pending_id        = $row['id'];
                $pending_user_id   = $row['user_id'];
                $pending_firstname = $row['firstname'];
                $pending_lastname  = $row['lastname'];
                $pending_username  = $row['username'];
?>
        <form action="" method="POST" id="status">
             <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $pending_id; ?>' id='pending_id'/>
<?php
        if ($pending_firstname == true) {
            echo "Name - ". $pending_firstname . " " . $pending_lastname . "</br>" . 
                "Username - ". $pending_username . "</br></br>"
                //echo print_r($_POST);
?>


                        <button class="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" value="<?=$pending_id;?>">Approve</button>
                        <button id="deny" type="submit" form="status" name="deny" value="Denied">Deny</button>
                        </form><br><br><br>
<?php   
                    ;} else {
                        echo "There are no Pending Requests at this time.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?>
<hr><br>

        <h2>Approved User Requests</h2><br>
        <div id="success" style="color: red;"></div><br>
    <?php
        $con2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
        $run2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
        $numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($run2);

            if( $numrows2 ) {
                while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run2)){
                    if($row2['status'] == "Approved"){

                        $approved_id        = $row2['user_id'];
                        $approved_firstname = $row2['firstname'];
                        $approved_lastname  = $row2['lastname'];
                        $approved_username  = $row2['username'];

        if ($approved_firstname == true) {
            echo "Name - ". $approved_firstname . " " . $approved_lastname . "</br>" . 
                "Username - ". $approved_username . "</br></br>"
?>
```

Comment: Does you php script return something, like say, some `JSON`? Also, that trailing `,` after your `success` function has to generate an error.

Comment: @Becky take a look at this example http://jsbin.com/quwukapana/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @bassxzero I'm honestly not sure what that is doing differently other than the alert messages coming up.

Comment: @Becky do you have a google hangout account?

Comment: @bassxzero no, I do not.

Comment: @Becky take a look now and let me know if you don't understand. http://jsbin.com/quwukapana/edit?html,js,output

Comment: How will this the while loop to work though or for the information to go into the Approved section?

Comment: @Becky What does the page look like? Do you have multiple forms or multiple approve and deny buttons in a single form?

Comment: I put in more of the html/php to show what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Becky Try the new section I added. It has everything I think you will need. Just copy/paste it into a new file (.php) and tell me if you get any errors. I have not error tested this code because I don't have a connection to your database.

Comment: No, it didn't. Here is the file you had me add ... http://sundayfundayleague.com/userRequest1.php ....you can see that it still requires a page load for the records to move.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. 
You are trapping the click event, which doesn't stop the form submission. 
If you change your handler to on submit and prevent the default action then this should work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#status').on('submit', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'userRequest_approve.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: $(this).val(), //id
            status: 'Approved' //status
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //do something with the data that got returned
            $("#success").fadeIn();
            $("#success").show();
            $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
            $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
        }
        //type: 'POST'
    });

});
});
```

Form

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="status">


  <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $pending_id; ?>' id='pending_id' />
    <?php if ($pending_firstname == true) { echo "Name - ". $pending_firstname . " " . $pending_lastname . "</br>" . "Username - ". $pending_username . "</br></br>" //echo print_r($_POST); ?>

<button class="approve" type="submit" form="status" name="approve" value="<?=$pending_id;?>">Approve</button>
<button id="deny" type="submit" form="status" name="deny" value="Denied">Deny</button>


</form>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<?php ;} else { echo "There are no Pending Requests at this time."; }
```

**NEW EDIT Section
TRY THIS**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
    $run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user_requests WHERE status='Pending' ORDER BY id DESC");
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($run);

    if( $numrows ) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
            if($row['status'] == "Pending"){

                $pending_id        = $row['id'];
                $pending_user_id   = $row['user_id'];
                $pending_firstname = $row['firstname'];
                $pending_lastname  = $row['lastname'];
                $pending_username  = $row['username'];

                if ($pending_firstname == true) {

                    // note removed ID
                    echo '<form action="" method="POST">';
                    echo "Name - " . $pending_firstname . " " . $pending_lastname . "</br>" . "Username - " . $pending_username . "</br></br>";
                    echo '<button class="approve" type="submit"  name="approve" action="Approved"  value="', $pending_id ,'">Approve</button>';
                    echo '<button class="deny" type="submit"  name="deny"  action="Denied"  value="', $pending_id ,'" >Deny</button>';
                    echo '</form><br><br><br>';

                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "There are no Pending Requests at this time.";
    }
?>
<hr><br>

<h2>Approved User Requests</h2><br>
<div id="success" style="color: red;"></div><br>
<?php
    $con2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
    $run2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT * FROM user_requests WHERE status='Approved' ORDER BY id DESC");
    $numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($run2);

    if( $numrows2 ) {

        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run2))
        {
            $approved_id        = $row2['user_id'];
            $approved_firstname = $row2['firstname'];
            $approved_lastname  = $row2['lastname'];
            $approved_username  = $row2['username'];

            if ($approved_firstname == true)
            {
                echo "Name - ". $approved_firstname . " " . $approved_lastname . "</br>" .
                    "Username - ". $approved_username . "</br></br>";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // none already in approved status

    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // button handler
        $('button').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            // get the button that was pressed
            var _button =  $(this);
            // get the value of this button
            var _val = _button.val();

            // get the action for the button (Either Approved or Denied)
            var _action = _button.attr('action');

            // get the form the button is in
            var _form = _button.closest('form');

            var _dataPassed = {status:_action,id:_val};

            // log the data I'm seding  (for debug)
            console.log(_dataPassed);

            // Trigger a submit event and pass the submit handler the value of the button pressed.    
            _form.triggerHandler('submit', _dataPassed);

        });


        $('form').submit(function (event, Passeddata) {
            // prevent the submit event so the page doesn't refresh.
            event.preventDefault();

            // make a ajax request with the value of the button that was pressed.
            $.ajax({
                url: 'userRequest_approve.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: Passeddata,
                success: function (data) {
                    //do something with the data that got returned
                    $("#success").fadeIn();
                    $("#success").show();
                    $('#success').html('User Status Changed!');
                    $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // alert on an http error
                    alert(textStatus + errorThrown);
                }
            });

        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing a `,` after `submit` and theres a trailing `,` after the `success` function. You can now also omit the `return false;`

Comment: @somethinghere thank you. I just copy and pasted his code and didn't notice that.

Comment: Doesn't work. Say John is a pending request and then I hit approve next to him, my php script will update my db, but without the page refreshing my while loop in the accepted section doesn't see it so nothing changes. I need the while loop to somehow see the change or a js function that will move John's name to the accepted section, until the page is reloaded and then the actual outputted data to be current.

Comment: Your answer also stopped my php script from running. Now nothing my db is being updated.

Comment: @Becky you need to put your submit buttons inside the <form> tag see my updates

Comment: No errors. Would it be helpful to add in my php page?

Comment: @Becky I see now. It's because in the submit handler $(this) refers to the form and you are sending $(this).val(); in your ajax data. You will need to select the correct buttons value.

Comment: So would I just do this? `$(this).val('Approved');`

Comment: @Becky it's not quite that simple. Give me a sec to create an example.